# Add custom menu option to JSQMessagesViewControllerCell

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am building a chat app that uses JSQMessagesViewController. The default functionality includes the ability for a user to long press a chat bubble which then presents a copy menu option (see screenshot). I would like to add an additional custom menu for reporting a comment. Ideally when the user long presses a chat bubble the menu now has two options, copy and report. Can someone please point me in the right direction for adding this custom menu button? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the demo file 
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesDemo/DemoMessagesViewController.m

See the use of customAction